# SQL Source Control and SQL Express "Support"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, redgate

Red Gate's SQL Source Control product documentation (http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SOC3/Requirements) states:

> SQL Source Control doesn't support SQL Server 2000, SQL Express, SQL Azure or SSMS Express

I have been evaluating their product and assumed based off this statement that "doesn't support" meant "will not work". However, I have made admittedly trivial changes to a central SQL Server Standard Edition database FROM a local SQL Express edition installation.

SQL Server edition differences notwithstanding - I am wondering what pitfalls this kind of architecture would have, again, strictly from a SQL Source Control perspective. We are looking for a way to bridge the gap between our planned upgrade to SQL Server 2012 from 2008 R2, and do not want to purchase 2008 dev edition licenses knowing that we have months until we start on our upgrade path.

Is anyone implementing a dedicated database development model with SQL Express on developer machines?

Comment: Have you considered using Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and then hosting your source code in Team Foundation Server or GIT?  SSDT Definitely works with both SQL Express 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: SVN integration is very tight with the Red Gate product, not to mention that we already use SVN throughout our environment. Adding another source control environment to administer (we are already using Mercurial also) isn't practical for us.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a pre-sales engineer for Redgate. We use SQL Express for most of the machines that we use in our own training courses for the same reason - licencing.

While it will *probably* work fine we don't officially support Express. The SQL Server editions that we say we support are the ones we test against. Given the number of SQL Server editions out there we only test against the ones we list on our website as officially supported. Hence we try to make it clear if you are using an edition that we do not test against.

However, assuming your dev databases are disposable and that your source of truth is your source code - which can be rolled back - and on the proviso that you understand our disclaimer that it is not officially supported, I'd unofficially say that it will *probably* work well enough.

*Sorry for not answering this a year ago. I've just started making an effort to be more pro-active on Stack!*